# Seeking help: song comparisons and analysis

Tags: analysis

I'm looking for some assistance in comparing songs to one another. Lately I've been noticing that listening to a song will remind me of another song or two that often aren't even the same genre, have no lyrics in common, the bpm aren't always even the same, etc. I am dying to know what it is about my brain that is finding similarities in these songs and what the actual common ground between them are, if there even are any!

Basically I'm wondering if I'm just going nuts, or if my brain is recognizing something subconsciously that's a pretty cool, unusual kind of "gift" possibly?

Usually I can pinpoint exactly which part of each song remind me of the other. When I point them out to other people, some say they hear what I'm talking about and some just look really confused. The ones claiming to understand what I'm hearing, but they too are unable to explain it describe it any better than I can, could just be pacifying me in order for me to stop trying to get them to hear it too. This happens to me multiple times/ day now. It's happening more and more often.

Here's an example from this morning: in my head I was thinking of the song "Calm Inside The Storm" by Cyndi Lauper. And towards the end of the song where there's a lot of "woah yeah woah yeah calm inside the storm love me a little love me long woah woah woah woah ya".. where it picks up a bit basically.. suddenly my thoughts turned to Isley Brother's "Shout", specifically the chorus, also towards the end where it picks up "you know you make me wanna shout kick my heels up and shout throw my hands up and shout C'mon now...". And my brain was thinking those could run together almost. And I'm wondering what they would sound like over-layed at those parts. Would there be a commonality? Would I need to slow one down and then they would match up somehow? What about those two made me connect the two?

I don't have any apps or musical tools to test these out. It would be cool if someone wanted to play with them and post it to show me that I'm either crazy or recognizing something unexpected? I don't even have a computer, just a cell phone and a tablet, so I can't buy or download software to test something like that.

So, anyone willing to give it a go? Or would other examples help? If so, I can reply here the next time it happens with different songs. Thanks to anyone willing to check on this for me.

Comment: If you study music and learn to play an instrument and write songs you’ll soon find it to be much easier to pinpoint what is similar and what is different between different works of music. Analyzing specific songs isn’t on topic here - we don’t want to build an unwieldy list of song trivia. You listed genre, lyrics, and “bpm” (more properly tempo) as being aspects of similarly or difference, and there are many more. Melody, harmony, chord progression, rhythms, chord voicing, vocal styles, and much more can make songs similar or different. Study those elements to better understand your ears.

Comment: By making this question more about what might make songs sound similar instead of asking about a specific instance between two songs it will be less likely to be closed and more useful to the community. I tried to answer along those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Based on [this source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rWRsJ-mDU5o) for "Shout" and [this source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVL7rycNE9s) for "Calm inside the storm"</sup>

I'd say that their keys are very close (they differ by a semitone), and the points you indicate have similar harmonic progressions: they both have the tonic in major mode in the first half, and the other half of the phrase is in the sixth degree (the relative minor).

Note that a progression is actually considered "similar" as long as its rhythm is also comparable, like in this case. In case there are only two chords, it's usually important that the order (which comes first) is respected too.

They are *not* exactly the same: "Shout" alternates those chords each other bar (or every two, depending on how you consider the base rhythm), while Lauper's progression lasts 8 bars (4 bars per chord) and it briefly goes to the dominant in the last 2 bars.

But, yes, they share the same aspects, harmonically speaking, and considering the similar key, that's probably the reason of your association.

Answer (score 0):

There are many elements to music that can cause even a person that doesn’t have any formal musical knowledge do find commonalities between two different pieces. Here are a few:

Melody: If two songs use the same or a very close sequence of notes in the melody it could be recognized by someone. This transcends key and genre.

Harmony: Two songs with a similar harmonic progression (chords) might cause someone to make a connection between them. In this case the songs would more likely be in a similar genre, for example, Doo-Wop ballads from the 1950’s.

Rhythm/drum beat/tempo: If two songs use the same or a similar rhythm or drum beat and are close to each other in tempo even non-musicians will sometimes find a correlation, especially if it is something that is more distinctive and uncommon. One example is “Can’t Hurry Love” (Supremes) and “Maneater” (Hall and Oates)

Instrument accompanying parts: Sometimes a guitar, bass or keyboard line will be played close to or exactly the same in two different songs creating a very strong connection between the two. (Bass line for “Ghostbusters and “I Want a New Drug”, can you say “lawsuit”?)

The bottom line is it can be one of more than one of the reasons I listed that will create an audible connection between two songs. Being an experienced musician makes it easy to identify the connection but even an untrained ear can sometimes put it together and figure out what it might be that unites two songs if they’re aware of the elements that will make them sound similar.